# The integral with respect to the Riesz measure over a compact with empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, potential-theory

Suppose $D$ is a bounded domain of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ($n\geq2$), $u$ a subharmonic function on $D$ and $\mu$ the Riesz measure associated with $u$. Let $F$ be a closed set with empty interior in $D$. Can we say:
$$\int_{F}\phi(t) d\mu(t)= \int_{F}u(t)\Delta\phi(t) dt$$ for all test function $\phi\in \mathscr D(D)?$ ($\Delta$ is the Laplace operator and $dt$ the Lebesgue meaure on $D$).

Notice that the above equality holds if the integrals are taken over $D$ instead of $F$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've studied this stuff, but I think Riesz measures can be point masses (i.e. there are subhamonic $u$ with $\Delta u = \delta_{x_0}$ in the sense of distributions). So taking $F$ to be that point immediately disproves your proposed equality, since integrating over a set of Lebesgue measure $0$ gives $0$.

Comment: If $F$ is a null set then both intergrals vanish and equality holds, no?

Comment: @M.Rahmat no. if $\mu = \delta_{x_0}$ is a point mass, then $\int_{\{x_0\}} \phi(t)d\mu(t) = \phi(x_0)$.

Comment: @M.Rahmat does my answer make sense now?

Comment: Sorry for delay. Than you,  could you please give a specific subharmonic function with $\mu=\delta_{x_{0}}$?

Comment: @M.Rahmat see the section on Laplace equation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_solution